# Refactor the code so this stream pipeline is used

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

Getting a bug in SonarQube with Refactor the code so this stream pipeline is used on following code snipts.

```
Stream<ContextData> stream = Globals.contextMap.values().stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(ContextData::getName));
```

How we can solve this ?.

Comments provided by sonarQube is,
Intermediate Stream methods should not be left unused.

But i have some other use of this stream after this line,

```
String contextName = parameterParser.getTagsWithValue().get(FilterParameter.CONTEXT_NAME);
if (contextName != null) {
    stream = stream.filter(entity -> entity.getName() !=null && entity.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(contextName));
}
```

Comment: You are not calling any terminal operation. So the stream is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should close stream :

ex. I collect the results to a list

```
List<ContextData>contextDataList = Globals.contextMap.values().stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(ContextData::getName))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```